# JavaScript doesn't work as expected in Thymeleaf and Spring Boot

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

JavaScript doesn't work in thymeleaf.

In Spring Boot Thymeleaf, first thing can open modal. But second, third ... things can not open modal.

Every thing has className, but only first thing can open modal.

I think JavaScript works only the first thing, and doesn't work other things.

```
<tr th:each="board, i : ${boards}">
                        <th scope="row" th:text="${i.count}">1</th>
                        <td>
                            <p class="show" th:text="${board.title}">Title</p>
                            <div class="modal"> .... </modal>
                        </td>
                        <td th:text="${board.writer}">Son</td>
                        <td th:text="${board.createDate}">2022-02-01</td></p>
</tr>
```

js

```
function show() {
    document.querySelector(".background").className = "background show";
}

function close() {
    document.querySelector(".background").className = "background";
}

document.querySelector(".show").addEventListener("click", show);
document.querySelector(".close").addEventListener("click", close);
```

please help me

Answer (score 1):

With your code you are only adding event listener to the **first element** of the class `".show"`. You should be adding event listeners to all members of the class. The following code should do the work:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.show').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', show);
})
```